# How can I disable a single option of checkboxes?

Tags: 8, forms, hooks

I am using domain access module in Drupal 8. I want to disable one option/site in domain access settings in node edit page . I am trying to disable through hook_node_form_alter. Following is my array in node form alter

Array
(

```
[widget] => Array
    (
        [#title] => Domain Access
        [#description] => stdClass Object
            (
                [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                [string] => Select the affiliate domain(s) for this content
            )

        [#field_parents] => Array
            (
            )

        [#required] => 1
        [#delta] => 0
        [#weight] => 0
        [#element_validate] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\OptionsButtonsWidget
                        [1] => validateElement
                    )

            )

        [#key_column] => target_id
        [#type] => checkboxes
        [#default_value] => Array
            (
                [0] => site1
                [1] => site3
            )

        [#options] => Array
            (
                [master] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                        [string] => Master
                    )

                [site1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                        [string] => Site 1
                    )

                [site2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                        [string] => Site 2
                    )

                [site3] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                        [string] => Site 3
                    )

                [site4] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [__CLASS__] => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup
                        [string] => Site 4
                    )

            )
```

)

Comment: have you tried ['#access'] => FALSE?
Or 'disabled' => TRUE?

Comment: I have tried this but its not working for individual options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Form Options Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/form_options_attributes) module and use the following code in `hook_form_alter()`.

```php
$form['field_domain_access']['widget']['#options_attributes']['your_option_key']  = ['disabled' => 'disabled'];
```

Comment: This helped me to create select list optroups (or similar behavior).

Answer (score 2):

A contrib module isn't required.

```
$form['field_domain_access']['your_option_key']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i can't disable checkbox by this way because it is a drupal element and use 'checkboxes' type.
Instead of reconstruct the entire element to use 'checkbox' type i add the attribute in the hook_preprocess because int the preprocess we have checkbox element by element like this :

```
if (
  isset($variables['element']['#type']) &&
  $variables['element']['#type'] === 'checkbox' &&
  $variables['element']['#return_value'] === RoleManagementServiceInterface::GROUP_CONTRIBUTOR_ROLE
) {
   $variables['attributes']['disabled'] = TRUE;
}
```